# How do modern devices communicate between local and public

Tags: networking, internet, connection, internet-connection

I recently bought a system that allows me to turn an outlet off and on via the web. The device uses a "bridge" and has a MAC Address & the "bridge" connects to my router through a RJ45/Ethernet connection.

My question how exactly is the communication scheme working? Not for this particular device, but in a system like this. When I use a command does the bridge act like a server to the home?

How would this device be set up without me configuring port forwarding on my router?

I'm very new to this side of things and I will take any kind of aid in assisting me in understand this system.

All in all I'm now interested in trying to create a similar system where i need to be able to pass info from a public server to a local device. The concept of doing so is what I'm lacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "bridge" is acting like a gateway.  Your home automation device looks for a compatible bridge device when it is powered on, likely via something like Bonjour.  Probably then it talks to the bridge device which relays communication to whatever central Internet-based service exists for this device.

The bridge or relay device, when it starts, likely contacts said central website, saying it is online and ready to accept commands.  Since it starts the connection, it will operate through the typical NAT set up no problem.  The bridge device likely continually polls this central server or keeps sending data to keep the connection alive.

Undoubtedly to actually tell this device to turn on and off, you likely log into that publicly available website not on your network.  The website then relays the command to the bridge, which has established a connection to this publicly available server earlier.  If it can't reach the bridge, it probably queues it and checks to see if the bridge comes up later for a while.

I'm sure the company running this website is capturing each time you want to turn on and off your outlet and selling the information for a tidy profit and you likely agreed to all this in the EULA.  :P

Now if you want to do a similar thing, you can set up some kind of relay or just have a server running in your house with the proper ports forwarded.

Comment: This is exactly what i was curious about... So what allows the bridge to be configured to accept communication without me(the user) having to set up my router for port foreward

Comment: Port forwarding doesn't do anything for connections that start inside your network and go out.

Comment: so the bridge is mostly likely acting like a client rather then a server? Ill give ya a check mark I promise just trying to wrap my head around this...If the connection starts inside my network... then a reply can be done to that connection without the need for port forwarding.

Comment: Right.  Port forwarding is for unsolicited incoming connections only.